# Inno Setup Place controls on wpPreparing Page

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I am trying to place a label on the `wpPreparing` page to indicate uninstallation of an existing version, prior to running the new installation. Here is my code:

```pascal
function PrepareToInstall(var NeedsRestart: Boolean): String;
var
  UninstallingLabel: TNewStaticText;
  intResultCode: Integer;
begin
  with UninstallingLabel do
    begin
      Caption := 'Uninstalling existing version...';
      Left := WizardForm.StatusLabel.Left;
      Top := WizardForm.StatusLabel.Top;
      Parent := wpPreparing.Surface;
    end;
  if strExistingInstallPath <> '' then
    begin
      Exec(GetUninstallString, '/verysilent /suppressmsgboxes', '', SW_HIDE,
        ewWaitUntilTerminated, intResultCode);
    end;
end;
```

The trouble is it does not seem to like `Parent := wpPreparing.Surface` and compiling fails with a

> Semicolon (;) expected

error. This syntax works when adding a label to a custom created page. Why does this fail when trying to add it to `wpPreparing`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `wpPreparing` is not an object, it's just a numerical constant.

The `WizardForm.PreparingPage` holds a reference to the "Preparing to Install" page. Note that it is of type `TNewNotebookPage` already, not `TWizardPage`. So you use it directly as a parent.

---

Also note that the `StatusLabel` is on the "Installing" page. You probably want to relate your new label to the `PreparingLabel` instead.

---

And you have to create the `UninstallingLabel`.

---

```pascal
UninstallingLabel := TNewStaticText.Create(WizardForm);

with UninstallingLabel do
begin
  Caption := 'Uninstalling existing version...';
  Left := WizardForm.PreparingLabel.Left;
  Top := WizardForm.PreparingLabel.Top;
  Parent := WizardForm.PreparingPage;
end;
```

---

Though do you really want to shadow the `PreparingLabel` (as you use its coordinates).

What about reusing it instead?

```pascal
WizardForm.PreparingLabel.Caption := 'Uninstalling existing version...';
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. `WizardForm.PreparingPage` was what I needed. I had accidentally omitted the label creation line in the code I posted. I am specifically not reusing the `PreparingLabel` and am referencing the `StatusLabel` coordinates, as the `PreparingLabel` is not aligned the same as the `StatusLabel` (it's further offset to the right). Maybe the `PreparingLabel` position could be modified to reflect that the of the `StatusLabel`, but I did not know how to do that, so went with creating my own label instead.

Answer (score 1):

I've replayed your code. It works if you use just `WizardForm` as the parent. But it's in the top left corner of the form...

`wpPreparing` is the name of a constant that holds the ID of the correspnding page.

And you have to create an instance of `UninstallingLabel`